# Asynctask with HttpClient and Progressbar

Tags: android, progress-bar, httpclient, android-asynctask

I am trying to get my HttpClient to work with Asynctask including a progressbar.
I already have this code of the Asynctask:

```
private class httpClient extends AsyncTask<String, Boolean, String> {

private HttpClient httpClient = getHttpClient();

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    publishProgress(true); 
    // Do the usual httpclient thing to get the result
    return null;
} 

@Override 
protected void onProgressUpdate(Boolean... progress) { 
    // line below coupled with  
    //    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS)  
    //    before setContentView  
    // will show the wait animation on the top-right corner 
    AndroidLogin.this.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(progress[0]); 
} 

@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
    publishProgress(false); 
    // Do something with result in your activity 
} 

}
```

My question is how to put below code correctly in the Asynctask, and that the Progressbar is also working.
Can somebody please help?

```
/******* INPUT USERNAME AND PASSWORD *******/
        EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username); // user input through EditText
        String username = uname.getText().toString();
        EditText pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_password); // password input through EditText
        String password = pword.getText().toString();

/******* INSTANTIATE THE CUSTOM HTTPCLIENT *******/
        HttpClient httpClient = getHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://xxx"); 

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usr_name", username)); 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usr_password", password)); 
        request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

/******* EXECUTE HTTPCLIENT *******/
        try  
        { 
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request); 

/******* READ CONTENT IN BUFFER *******/
        InputStream inputStreamActivity = response.getEntity().getContent();  
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStreamActivity));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
/******* CLOSE CONNECTION AND STREAM *******/
        System.out.println(sb);
            inputStreamActivity.close();
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.
I needed to include the Textfields into the Asynctask, to avoid the Exception.

```
EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
EditText pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
```

I decided to use a ProgressDialog instead of a Progressbar, following needs to be added:

```
//Create a Progressdialog
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MyApp.this);

@Override 
    protected void onPreExecute()  
    { 
        //Set the Progressdialog
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER); 
        pd.setMessage("Getting data....");
                 }

 @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... args) { 
           //Update the Progressdialog
           pd.setProgress(args[0]); 
           } 

  @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
        //Dismiss Progressdialog
        pd.dismiss();
                 }
```

That`s it..

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use onPreExecute for ProgressBar init** and among another things which are not about your important stuff:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() 
{
     publishProgress(true); 
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{
     funtiontoallthatbigcodeorcodeitselfhere(); 
}

...
```

Comment: Hi A.Quiroga,
I get a force close now, does not seems to function.

Comment: 10-16 13:32:52.735: WARN/dalvikvm(8257): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x401ba560)

Comment: I also had to make a try-catch around:
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usr_password", password));

Comment: Here is the error from Logcat:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8675): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.sencide/com.sencide.AndroidLogin}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: A.Quiroga, you`re still there?

Comment: put all LogCat in your answer .

Comment: ok , but please put it in an answer in order to help anothers who has the same problem than you

Comment: I`ll have to wait for 8 hours, because i have less then 100 reputation.
But i will post the solution to this.